# Using preprocessor macros to compose another macro call

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have a C++ preprocessor macro defined as follows:

```
#define X(s) std::cout << #s
```

if I use it directly:

```
int main() {
    X( hello );
}
```

It works as expected and "hello" is printed on the console.

If I define another macro that calls it:

```
#define Y X( hello )
#define X(s) std::cout << #s

int main() {
    Y;
}
```

It still works.

However if I try to compose the call to `X` from two or more different macros, I get a whole bunch of errors:

```
#define A X(
#define B hello
#define C )

#define X(s) std::cout << #s << '\n'


int main()
{
    A B C;
}
```

See output at: http://cpp.sh/5ws5k

Why can't I compose a macro call from two or more macro expansions, doesn't preprocessor expand them recursively?

Comment: You should read a documentation describing the [C++ preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), perhaps the C++11 or C99 standard. It does not work like you are dreaming.

Comment: I have not idea what you are trying to achieve here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why can't I compose a macro call from two or more macro expansions, doesn't preprocessor expand them recursively?

You can compose macros. The pre-processor does expand macros recursively.

However, it doesn't expand the macros width first. It expands them depth first.

You are running into a problem because you want the pre-processor to expand the macros width first.

You can read more about recursive macro expansion in **16.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement** of the C++11 standard.

Comment: Relevant C++ Standard quote: 16.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement

Comment: As for "depth" and "width," the preprocessor does both. Moving the open paren from `A` to `B`, and given `#define I(Q) Q`, and using `I(A B C)`, it [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffc76f2b99c9c45a).